# Cannot connect to home WiFi network

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-10, wifi-configuration

I upgraded to Windows 10 and ever since then my computer can't find my own home wifi network. A bunch of available wifi networks will show up, but not mine. I don't have it hidden and it shows up on my Blackberry & my Samsung Galaxy. Ethernet works fine, but not wifi.

I've tried the following:

- Use device manager and scroll to network adapters and expand it and select your wifi card. from there hit uninstall but do not remove the driver. after that look up top for a computer with a magnifying glass and it will scan for changes which will then reinstall your driver for your wireless.
- I tried to "manually connect to a wireless network" which still didn't work (I could name it, and enter the password) but nothing would happen.
- I've upgraded the drivers of my Dell Centrino card and I still don't see my wifi network.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Deleting the existing *Wireless Network Profile* might help, if it is faulty. See http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3507-wireless-network-profile-delete-windows-10-a.html for deleting one profile, or http://www.thewindowsclub.com/forget-wireless-network-profiles-windows-10 to get rid of all.

Comment: Tried that and i still don't see own wifi network.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Sometimes the Web upgrade to Windows 10 has issues. Try to do an [In-place ugrade](http://superuser.com/a/987707/8672) using a full Windows 10 installation media.

Comment: I've actually installed the full enterprise version of Win 10 and I still don't see my network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following experiment, login to your Wi-Fi router, make sure it is broadcasting its SSID. If it is already broadcasting, change the SSID to something else. See if it shows up on your PC. If it shows up and you can connect, it is likely something to do with your wireless network profile. But since you said deleting the Wireless Network Profile didn't help, it is be something else.

Does your Wi-Fi router configured on a specific frequency? Say, 5.8GHz? Or specific mode (e.g. N-mode only). If yes, try changing it.

Try to boot your PC using Ubuntu via CD or USB. And confirm Wi-Fi discovery works.

You can also rollback to Windows 8 and try again. But if wireless is your only problem, I think it may do more harms than good.

Comment: Changing the configuration to a different mode did the trick for me.  Thx for the pointer.